# angularjs $compile html template in forEach not update variables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-templates

I want to dynamically generate html. I have generateHtml function contains loop for items, currently it is not displaying proper variables added in template. It is always display the last items data on all the iteration on compiled html.
Following is the controller & template code

This is my controller code

```
angular.module('app').controller('PageController', ['$scope', '$sce', '$compile','$templateRequest',
    function ($scope, $sce, $compile,$templateRequest) {
        $scope.itemsHtml = '';
        // Array contains dynamic data
        vm.items = [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'abc',
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'pqr',
        }, {
            id: 3,
            name: 'stu',
        }, {
            id: 4,
            name: 'xyz',
        }];
        vm.currentItem = [];
        
        let templateUrl = $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl('/views/item.html');

        $templateRequest(templateUrl).then(function(template) {
            vm.itemTemplate = template;
        }, function() {
        });

        vm.generateHtml = function() {
            items.forEach(function (item, key) {
                vm.currentItem = item;

                let compiledTemplate = $compile(vm.itemTemplate)($scope).html();

                /* Append compiled dynamic html */
                $scope.itemsHtml += compiledTemplate;
            });
        }

        function init() {
            vm.generateHtml();
        }
        
        init();
    }
]);
```

This is template view

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="item.html">
    <div className="item-wrapper">
        <div className="item-inner">
            {{ pageCtrl.currentItem.name }}
        </div>
        <div className="action-inner">
            <div className="btn-action"
                 role="button"
                 ng-click="pageCtrl.edit(
                                pageCtrl.currentItem.id
                            )">
                <i className="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: I can't spot anything wrong, but maybe there's some odd behavior having to do with variable scoping and callbacks inside `items.forEach()`. Try using an old school `for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { let item = items[i] }` and see if that fixes it

Comment: @JacobStamm Thanks for your reply, but it is still having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for this issue.

Actually when we use compile after that we have to interpolate the compiled template

**compiledTemplate = $interpolate(compiledTemplate)($scope);**

```
let compiledTemplate = $compile(vm.itemTemplate)($scope).html();

/* Here interpolated compiled template */
compiledTemplate = $interpolate(compiledTemplate)($scope);

/* Append compiled dynamic html */
$scope.itemsHtml += compiledTemplate;
```

Comment: I see. So it wasn’t interpolating until the end, at which point at the variables were of the last element in the list.